# Entity Framework Core cascade on delete,

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to configure my entities that they will have appropriate relations. 
I want to configure it that, when I remove category entity, it should disappear from database with its translation and all of products of this category(including products translations of course).

It works but not fully.
At this moment when I remove category, all products of this category are removed, but translations(category and products) stays.

My entities:

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public Category Category { get; protected set; }
    public Translation Translation { get; protected set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; protected set; }
    public Translation Translation { get; protected set; }
}

public class Translation
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string English { get; protected set; }
    public string Polish { get; protected set; }
    public string Gernam { get; protected set; }
}
```

DbContext configuration

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasMany(x => x.Products).WithOne(x => x.Category)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);


modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasOne(x => x.Category).WithMany(x => x.Products)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

It it possible to configure dbcontext that it will works as I want WITHOUT adding Category, and Product properties to Translation entity?

Comment: What's the type of the relationship between `Product` and `Translation`? One-to-one?

Comment: Yest but I want to prevent adding Product property in Trabslation

Comment: If you mean inverse navigation property, it's not mandatory. But the main point is that in order to cascade delete the `Translation` from `Product`, the `Product` must be the **principal** of the relationship, hence `Translation` table must have FK to `Product`. Same applies to `Category` -> `Translation`. Which means that what you are asking is not possible, because such design will create *multiple cascade paths*, i.e. won't allow you setting the cascade delete option.